# Redirect users to the correct database according to their country on the url, i worked with i18n for php and im using kohana framework

Tags: php, mysql, apache, internationalization, kohana

I have arrays of data that can contain the database connection parameters but i dont know how to make it dynamic inside the application, i used i18n for currency and major country strings i though on storing this database connection params into the i18n files from country and just use it like this     __('database_array_params') looking like this file:

```
<?php

return array(
'CountryName' => 'Perú',
'CountryForVariable' => 'perú',
'locale_id' => 'pe',
'CurrencyForPricing' => 'Soles',
'CurrencyIsoCode' => 'PEN',
'CurrencySymbol' => 'S/',
'CurrencySign' => 'S/. ',
'CountryLat' =>  '-12.046374',
'CountryLong' => '-77.042793',

'TopCities' =>
    array(
        array(
            'CityName' => 'Lima',
            'PostalCode' => 'Blah'
        ),
        array(
            'CityName' => 'Cusco',
            'PostalCode' => 'Blah'
        ),
        array(
            'CityName' => 'Puno',
            'PostalCode' => 'Blah'
        ),
        array(
            'CityName' => 'Arequipa',
            'PostalCode' => 'Blah'
        )
    ),

'default' =>
    array(
        'type'       => 'MySQL',
        'connection' => array(
            'hostname'   => '127.0.0.1',
            'database'   => 'database_name',
            'username'   => 'root',
            'password'   => '123',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
        'profiling'    => FALSE,
    ),

 );
```

i feel this is a bad approach how can i get my objective with a cleaner approach?

Comment: Your solution need to be only in php or can be in apache config side?

Comment: im open to config apache thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very, very dirt solution but maybe can help.

Create a php file for every database you have (let's suppose there are 3 and your php file to connect the database is confic.php). So, config1.php for access come from Asia and Oceania, config2.php to Americas e config3.php to Europe and Africa.

You can use the rewrite rule as the example below (sample of connection from canada.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /country=CA*
RewriteRule (.+)$ /config2.php
```

Comment: where exactly should i add that ? im kinda new to this plz some example